Invoke REST API and store the json response to snowflake table
I want to invoke the REST API and the API params will be dynamic. params will be start_date and end_date. end_date should be current_timestamp and start_date should be 1 day before. I could use custom connector for static API endpoint, but is it possible to pass those dates to the API endpoint dynamically?
If not, I was thinking of writing python script. which component should I use?
Normally the below script works in my machine, but I was getting this error in matillion.
Python Interpreter Error:

ConnectionError:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', port=443):
Max retries exceeded with url: /todos (Caused by
NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at
0xffff716f5db0>: Failed to resolve 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'
([Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution)"))
Script failed

Here is the script:
import requests

def get_users():
    url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        print("Failed to fetch users. Status code:", response.status_code)
        return None

users = get_users()
print(users)

I want to store the JSON response in snowflake variant column.
